SharePoint 2016: After changing FarmAdmin password, Central admin throwing error
We have changed password for SharePoint 2016 Farm Admin credentials.
-Changed in AD; Updated using PowerShell in SharePoint server

Set-SPManagedAccount - UseExistingPassword -Identity DOMAINA\SPSAdmin
-Prompt for the password and entered the updated password
-Repair-SPManagedAccountDeployment
-IISRESET


Unable to change SharePoint account password in SharePoint 2010

After that, Central admin is not opening. Throwing error Server Error in '/' Application.
Steps we did:
-Changed back to old password from AD.
-Changed password from IIS App Pool
-Run Config wizard - Not running as it is not able to connect to configuration database
Looks like password change is not reflected properly.
Can anyone have any idea how to proceed?
Any help is highly appreciated.
Edit:
Getting below error when opening SharePoint Management Shell:

The local farm is not accessible. Cmdlets with FeatureDependencyId are
not registered. You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
Extensions\16\CONFIG\POWERSHELL\Registration\SharePoint.ps1:10 char:1

$adminWebApp.GetEndOfSupportMessage($false, [ref]$endOfSupportSeverit ...

  + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull




You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At C:\Program
Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
Extensions\16\CONFIG\POWERSHELL\Registration\SharePoint.ps1:13 char:1

$adminWebApp.GetEndOfSupportSeverityLevelData($endOfSupportSeverityLe
...

  + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull





In the script you ran it does not look as you are actually updating the farm with the new (nor old password) after changing it in your AD.
Try this instead (as an admin) to update your farm with the new farm account password.
$FarmAccount = "DOMAINA\SPSAdmin"
$Password = "farmAccountPassword" -AsSecureString
Set-SPManagedAccount -Identity $FarmAccount -ExistingPassword $Password -UseExistingPassword $true


Thanks for the reply: Got below error:Set-SPManagedAccount : Cannot access the local farm. Verify that the local farm is properly configured, currently
available, and that you have the appropriate permissions to access the database before trying again.
At line:1 char:1

Set-SPManagedAccount -Identity $FarmAccount -ExistingPassword $Passwo ...

+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...tManagedAccount:SPCmdletSetManagedAccount) [Set-SPManage

dAccount], SPCmdletException

FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletSetManagedAccount




Also, modified the script; Above was getting error:$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "password" -AsPlainText -Force
Set-SPManagedAccount -Identity $FarmAccount -ExistingPassword $Password -UseExistingPassword:$true

Were you trying to set the old password that you switched back to? Did you change it back in IIS were you changed it (changing it in IIS should not been necessary). If you check the Services on the server hosting central administration - are the services related to SharePoint stopped? Try to change the password there manually for the services related to the farm account to the current one and then start them if they're stopped.

Regarding the error message you see in PowerShell: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/07/the-local-farm-is-not-accessible-cmdlets-with-featuredependencyid-are-not-registered-powershell-error.html

After the issue started. I have reset with old password in AD. But issue not resolved. Tried changing in IIS too. Also services updated manually. Now Central Admin app pool is getting stopped continuously. Local farm issue started after changing password only, before that it worked

As you ran the command the first time with the new password, you could try to set that instead if the services is stopping because of a password miss-match (setting the old password).

After updating credentials in IIS, central admin app pool starts. But Central admin throwing same error. As I am not able to successfully run the password update Powershell due to Local farm error. Also, not able to run the wizard. Whether disconnecting server from Farm and add again is a good idea?

I'm unsure but I think that the problem would persist. Did you see the article i posted regarding the local farm error?

yes. farmadmin account already have those access. I guess, Shell Admin access is also corrupted. Not able to run any of those powershell scripts

I'm sad to hear that. You don't have the account that were used to set up the farm with? That account should have all the necessary permissions to make the change using PowerShell.
